# Is there any command similar to "rails destroy" in Phoenix Framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there any quick way to undo the actions of generators do Phoenix Framework?

*Automatically translated from Brazilian Portuguese.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it's an interesting question, but as far as I know there is **no** such way built-in.

The way phoenix generators works are not the same like in rails. These generators are mostly for creating some simple boilerplate files with some simple code parts to save your time for bootstrapping.

So `phoenix.gen.*` will create just files.. 
I'd suggest to use git, for your code..

But for `ecto.migrate` there is `ecto.rollback` Task to rollback your DB.